# how can I make this sql join request

Tags: mysql, sql, count, inner-join, self-join

How can get this : the last name (nom), first name (prenom) and age of competitors that participated at all competitons. I have difficulties with count and join.

my user table :

| id | nom | prenom | login | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Wehner | Einar | kleinviola | 79 |
| 2 | Beer | Cierra | earnestinelebsa | 71 |
| 3 | Gina | Lucien | cassindagmar | 97 |
| 4 | Maybelle | Delphine | haleypredovic | 91 |
| 5 | Upton | Elwyn | sstreich | 63 |
| 6 | Irwin | Prof. | christopframi | 25 |
| 7 | Ernser | Clint | cesar65 | 83 |
| 8 | Bechtelar | Sheila | sofiasawayn | 77 |
| 9 | Simonis | Remington | christafahey | 35 |
| 10 | Parisian | Octavia | swiftsage | 89 |
| 11 | Predovic | Rory | bartolettisabri | 78 |
| 12 | Will | Sven | price66 | 20 |
| 13 | O'Hara | Zoey | tiffanywillms | 96 |
| 14 | McGlynn | Julie | gkoss | 74 |
| 15 | Walter | Maximus | amandajenkins | 63 |
| 16 | Hahn | Andrew | drutherford | 77 |
| 17 | Kunze | Elinore | ziemanntheron | 95 |
| 18 | Ursula | Evelyne | collierodessa | 64 |
| 19 | Klein | Kirsten | darrellrunolfss | 96 |
| 20 | Chester | Lucien | jamey55 | 24 |
| 21 | Darron | Antoine | justina27 | 60 |
| 22 | Boyer | Harvey | hesseljameson | 45 |
| 23 | Jade | Lucien | kpagac | 29 |
| 24 | Eliane | Delphine | delphahessel | 75 |
| 25 | Lang | Shanna | sophia73 | 23 |
| 26 | Wilderman | Fredrick | shaina75 | 34 |
| 27 | Daniel | Emie | alene73 | 86 |
| 28 | Daniel | Rhoda | foster22 | 63 |
| 29 | Trantow | Tommie | boconner | 40 |
| 30 | Kerluke | Adolf | vstanton | 74 |
| 31 | Sehoubo | David | davidshbo | 20 |
| 32 | dfglskdsklj | dfvdvf | dfgdfg | 0 |

my competitors table :

| id_competitor | id_concours |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 31 | 1 |
| 9 | 2 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 11 | 2 |
| 12 | 2 |
| 13 | 2 |
| 14 | 2 |
| 15 | 2 |
| 16 | 2 |
| 17 | 2 |
| 18 | 2 |
| 31 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 19 | 3 |
| 20 | 3 |
| 31 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 8 | 4 |
| 10 | 4 |
| 12 | 4 |
| 14 | 4 |
| 16 | 4 |
| 18 | 4 |
| 20 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 9 | 5 |
| 11 | 5 |
| 13 | 5 |
| 15 | 5 |
| 17 | 5 |
| 19 | 5 |

my competitons table:

| id | date_debut | date_fin | descriptif | theme | etat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 2019-03-01 00:00:00 | Le premier concours de la plateforme | Les zinzins de l'espace | 4 |
| 2 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | Le deuxième concours de la plateforme | Outils | 4 |
| 3 | 2020-04-01 00:00:00 | 2020-05-01 00:00:00 | Le troisième concours de la plateforme | Voiture sur autoroute | 2 |
| 4 | 2018-07-01 00:00:00 | 2018-08-11 00:00:00 | Le quatrième concours de la plateforme | Naruto Uzumaki | 3 |
| 5 | 2018-10-01 00:00:00 | 2018-11-01 00:00:00 | Le cinquième concours de la plateforme | Le grand peuple au dessus de la mer | 4 |

Comment: What is exactly the question? Can you also provide something that you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should return the name, first name and age of all users that participated in ALL competitions:

```
SELECT nom, prenom, age
FROM user
WHERE (SELECT count(DISTINCT id_concours) FROM competitors WHERE id_competitor = user.id) = (SELECT count(*) FROM competitons);
```